# I can't access my website after installing certbot SSL on gcloud

Tags: ssl-certificate, google-cloud-platform, wordpress, google-compute-engine, certbot

I followed this tutorial on [how to install let's encrypt ssl on Google cloud](https://onepagezen.com/free-ssl-certificate-wordpress-google-cloud-click-to-deploy/)

Everything was working fine before installing but after install the certbot on my WordPress click to deploy site running on Google compute engine,I have only been able to access my website using https://softwarebtc.net , if I use www.softwarebtc.net or softwarebtc.net I receive an error saying server IP not found . I have checked through my cloud DNS to see if it pointing to the right IP, and I see no problem there, I've changed the site setting in WordPress to https://softwarebtc.net it still the same thing.

I'm stuck. Is there a way I can uninstall it.

Answer (score 1):

I just visited your website and it seems to be working very fine at my end including the SSL. Your website [softwarebtc.net](https://cutewebstats.com/info/softwarebtc.net) seems to be pointed to 35.239.242.194 which I assume is the correct IP address. Clear your browser's chache and try again. it should be very fine for you now. There might be temporraily DNS cache issue or browser cache issue to your end.

Comment: Yea thanks, I was able to fix it earlier this morning.

Answer (score 1):

It figured it out .. thanks

Actually I was unable to uninstall the SSL which I guess was the cause of the problem. I had to export my WordPress site using all in one wp migration, then deployed WordPress again on a separate VM whilst the other was still running, installing all in one wp migration again on the  new VM, I imported my site into it, then went further to shutdown the previous vm, I updated my permalink and site address to http, then changed my DNS record to point to the new Instance IP and that was all..